# Relation error when pushing mysql to heroku

Tags: mysql, django, ruby, heroku, sequel

I'm trying to push my local mysql database to my heroku postgres database using valkyrie with the following:

```
valkyrie mysql://localhost/themedb postgres://DATABASE__COLOR_URL/here
```

It appears to start running well but then encounters with a constraint error than I cant figure out:

```
Transferring 17 tables:
auth_group:     100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:02
auth_group_per: 100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:00
auth_message:   100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:00
auth_permissio: 100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:02
auth_user:      100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:00
auth_user_grou: 100% |=========================================| Time: 00:00:00
C:/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.31.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgre
s.rb:181:in `async_exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "user_id" already exists(Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

I think these models are from `django.contrib.auth` and I dont see why there's a relation error. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm having the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in valkyrie. 
Here's an explanation of the issue from the [valkyrie source](https://github.com/ddollar/valkyrie/blob/master/lib/sequel/extensions/schema_to_hash.rb#L129):

> mysql index namespaces are per table, vs per database, so it is possible for
>   there to be, in a mysql to postgresql migration, index name conflicts.

The solution is also detailed:

> this code checks to see if its coming *from* a mysql database to postgresql,
>   and, if so, makes sure that an attempt to create a second idx of the same name
>   doesn't results in a failed migration, but just renames the index to prepend
>   table name

Note that `gem install valkyrie` doesn't install the 'fixed' version. You have to get the latest code from github which works great.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your destination database is empty? The error explicitly tells you, that user_id field exists already while you're trying to create it.

Comment: I guess it should be, I created it just before transfering.

Comment: Did you by chance run syncdb on the new db?

Comment: No I didn't. I also just tried resetting it with heroku pg:reset, but error still happens when I try to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your source data in MySQL clean?  Are constraints checked in your MySQL database, and are you using InnoDB?

Looks like there could be a duplicate entry in your dev database.

Comment: What do you mean by clean, and how can I check if it is? Anyways, the table that is causing the error is empty.

Comment: What is the table that is causing the error -- can you add that to the question? By clean, I mean that there are no duplicates where there shouldn't be and FK relations exist, etc. (if MySQL is enforcing these constraints, that should be good enough).